# Pandas Apply with Lambda Function

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried to simplify my problem to the bear bones in the example below. I am attempting to `apply` a function to a pandas data frame (much more complex than the one below) but the function contains an if statement that throws a Value Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I handle passing a series to this lambda function without incurring this error?

```
def shot_test(make, att):
  if att > 75:
    return make / att
  else:
    return 0

f = lambda x: np.where(x.total > 30, shot_test(x.make, x.att), 0)
df['P'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Your sample work for me

Answer (score 0):

I used some made up data, but I believe this should get you what you are looking for IIUC.

```
def shot_test(make, att):
    if att > 75:
        return make / att
    else:
        return 0

trips = {'Column1':[0, 2, 19, 15, 0,  23, 0, 0, 10,0],
        'Column2':[1, 2, 15, 1, 4,  22, 1, 0, 143,5],
        'Column3':[2, 1, 54, 543, 34,  243, 7, 0, 213,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(trips)
df['Lambda_Test'] = df.apply(lambda x : shot_test(x['Column2'], x['Column3']) if x['Column1'] >= 10 else 0, axis = 1)
df
```

This will allow you to pass multiple column arguments into the shot_test function as well as testing if a separate column meets a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two example uses of your code, one which works and one which generates your error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def shot_test(make, att):
  if att > 75:
    return make / att
  else:
    return 0

f = lambda x: np.where(x.total > 30, shot_test(x.make, x.att), 0)

print("\nTest #1:")
df = pd.DataFrame({'total':[25,50,60], 'make':[300,500,1000], 'att':[100,100,50]})
print(df)
df['P'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)


print("\nTest #2:")
df = pd.DataFrame({'total':[25,50,60], 'make':[300,500,1000], 'att':[pd.Series([100,50]),pd.Series([100,50]),pd.Series([50,100])]})
print(df)
df['P'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Test #1:
   total  make  att
0     25   300  100
1     50   500  100
2     60  1000   50
   total  make  att    P
0     25   300  100  0.0
1     50   500  100  5.0
2     60  1000   50    0

Test #2:
   total  make                             att
0     25   300  0    100
1     50
dtype: int64
1     50   500  0    100
1     50
dtype: int64
2     60  1000  0     50
1    100
dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX.py", line 23, in <module>
    df['P'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
  File "YYY\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8833, in apply
    return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
  File "YYY\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 727, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "YYY\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 851, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "YYY\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 867, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "XXX.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: np.where(x.total > 30, shot_test(x.make, x.att), 0)
  File "XXX.py", line 6, in shot_test
    if att > 75:
  File "YYY\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1535, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

As you can see, in the second example, each value in column `att` of the dataframe is itself a pandas Series, and this is triggering the error on this line:

```py
  if att > 75:
```

Assuming the data in the `att` column can be easily transformed from Series to scalar, you can do this and modify the line of code above to be unambiguous. However, if `att` is indeed supposed to be a Series (or other array-like structure) with multiple values, you may need to rethink the logic of your code.

Comment: @a.powell Do you need any additional help with your question?